# How to filter facebook offers based on their location?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

It will be very helpful if someone tells me how to filter the facebook offers based on user's current location. Is there any possible way to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this myself..

I used the following FQL query to do so.

```
SELECT id, title, owner_id, image_url, created_time, expiration_time, terms, claim_limit, coupon_type, redemption_link, redemption_code FROM offer WHERE owner_id IN (SELECT parent_page FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id,name FROM place WHERE distance(latitude, longitude, '-36.849423','174.755888') < 50000))
```